# How to solve the problem that "File `pdftexcmds.sty' not found. \RequirePackage{pdftexcmds}[2018/01/30]"?

Tags: bibliographies, pdftex, biber

Coding:

```
\documentclass{ctexart}

\usepackage[style=numeric, backend=biber]{biblatex} 
\addbibresource{test.bib}

\begin{document}
    \cite{hubert_how_1990}

    \parencite{_tex_2019}

    \supercite{_xml-tex-pdf_201}

    \printbibliography 
\end{document}
```

Log File:

```
! LaTeX Error: File `pdftexcmds.sty' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)

Enter file name: 
! Emergency stop.
<read *> 

l.37 \RequirePackage{pdftexcmds}[2018/01/30]
                                            ^^M
*** (cannot \read from terminal in nonstop modes)
```

Platform: `TexLive2019`，`Windows10 64bit`

Compiler: `XeLaTeX`, Bibliography Tool: `Biber`

Comment: Install `pdftexcmds`. On the command line you probably need something like `tlmgr install pdftexcmds`. (`pdftexcmds` and several other packages were recently split from the `oberdiek` bundle. They are now stand-alone packages and need to be installed separately. Many people install full TeX live systems with all packages, so they are not affected by this split. But if you only installed selected packages to get your files working, you may have to install some missing packages now.)

Comment: Thanks. I think maybe I need to reinstall the full edition of TeX Live. For when I install the `pdftexcmds`, another package missing is occured.

Comment: Well, the `oberdiek` split split off quite a few packages. It might be tedious to go through the list, but you have to do it only once. (Of course you can still use the TeX live manager/`tlmgr` to install the full list of packages, without having to reinstall all of TeX live.)

Comment: So far we've only seen problems with the split if you didn't install the full tl19.

Comment: I just finished reinstalling and it is ok now. Thanks so much.

Comment: Great. I think we could close this question as a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/518757/35864

Comment: Sorry, I hadn't searched that answer before I posted. I agree, but how to close? Just delete?